# How to set status and get status (picture & video like instagram story) with go whatsmeow library

Tags: go, whatsapp

I'm trying to get notified about my contacts' status(picture & video) changes on whatsapp using whatsmeow go library. The library doesn't specifically mention this feature on the documentations.
Does anyone know if this feature is supported or if there is a work around for it?
Also does this comply with whatsapp terms of services or no?

I tried to check whatsapp web client and their business api but I could not find a clue.